# Yield call returns a promise

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, saga

So I am trying to learn react-redux-saga.  I am building a simple application that just grabs user data from an API and displays it.  Here is my generator function in my saga:

```
export function* fetchImage() {
      try {
        const response = yield call(fetch, 'https://randomuser.me/api/');
        console.log("Response 111", response);
        const responseBody = response.json();
        yield put(setImage(response));
      } catch (e) {
        yield put(fetchFailed(e));
      }
      return;

    }
```

It simply does a yield call to a url and then dispatches an action.  However, the response object isn't coming back as JSON, instead it looks like its returning some response object:

[image]

I'm not sure what to do with this object.  If you hit the URL directly through the browser it returns a JSON object.  How do I get it to return JSON?

So my response.json() is returning this object:

[image]

Looks like my object that I want is in the [[PromiseValue]] thing.  What is that and how do I get to my value?

Comment: The library that you using which has these `call` and `put` is wrapping your response in a Response object. 
Do you know the library? If yes, then check its documentation, it would probably turn out to be as easy as accessing that JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always access the body of the response object after it's resolved:

`const response = yield call(fetch, 'https://randomuser.me/api/');
const responseBody = yield response.json(); // HERE is what you want`

Comment: I did that but its returning a [[PromiseValue]] thing and my object is in there.  How do I get my value out of there?  I edited my question.

Comment: did you call `response.json` with `yield` ?

Comment: Like this?:
yield call(fetch, response.json());
This gave me the same thing as before.

Comment: `yield response.json();`

Answer (score 4):

Just another way to do the same job, by making use of `call` method.

```
const response = yield call(fetch, 'https://randomuser.me/api/');
const body = yield call([response, 'json']);
console.log(body)
```

Another way

```
const body =  yield call([response, response.json]);
```